# Popup menu using ImageButton

Tags: android

Im my project I have a layout inflated in an adapter. and I have an ImageButton set to show popup menu
all the menus are added programatically. But when I run the project and click the buttom, the app shuts down with the following error;

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in com.example.ghanlice:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040158 a=-1}
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040158 a=-1}

The crazy part is, I have the same popup on other adapter working perfectly. I just can't figure out why this isn't working.

layout xml file

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/achieve_more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
    />
```

adapter java file

```
 PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, achieveMore, Gravity.END);

        if (uid.equals(myUid))
        {
            //add items to menu
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 0,0, "Delete post");
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1,0, "Edit post");
        }
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 2,0,"View details");

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    //delete is clicked
                    deleteWithImage(pid, image);
                }
                else if (id == 1)
                {
                    //Edit is clicked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddAchievement.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", "editPost");
                    intent.putExtra("editPostId", pid);
                    intent.putExtra("editType", type);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

                else  if (id == 2)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AchievementDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("postId", pid);
                    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After straggling two days without any solution, I finally got the problem solved!
what I did was to delete
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;
and then add
import android.widget.PopupMenu;

case closed !!